# If A = BC and B is invertible why must null(A) = null(C)

Tags: linear-algebra

Hey I'm reviewing for my linear exam and on the review sheet my teacher asks me...

```
  Suppose A = BC where B is an invertible matrix, then null(A) = null(C).
```

I see that the answer is "true" in the solutions but I really have no clue why. is it just that for any vector *v* s.t. Av = 0, and knowing that A = BC, BC*v* must also be zero and we can reduce to C*v* = 0 to by multiplying by B^-1? I'm just suspicious and while my explanation might be right I really have no conceptual understanding of what is going on here.

Thanks :)

Comment: Yes, your explanation is correct.

Comment: $Cv=0\implies BCv=0\implies Av=0$; $Av=0\implies B^{-1}Av=0\implies Cv=0$.